# Butterworth filter

Tags: matlab, filters, butterworth

Can someone please explain how would the image of a biosignal say PPG be affected when a higher-order Butterworth filter is used. Please don't tell about bode curve, I need practical aspects of it.
What is the practical implication of a narrow transition band with higher-order filters on a signal?

Comment: sorry, what kind of practical aspects do you need? The Bode diagram very clearly illustrates the effects of a filter on the components of your signal, it doesn't get much more practical than that, I'm afraid, but maybe I just don't see what you mean. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Hi marcus, I am new to signals . I just wanted to know why I should apply only butter worth order 2 to PPG signals. What is the effect on image ( on signal amplitude and width) if  I use order 3 order 4 and so on. What is the effect of a narrower transition band on signals

Comment: the effects are exactly what the Bode diagram says they are – what kind of description of an effect are you hoping for?

Comment: Narrow transition band means more temporal ringing (unless the filters are Bessel/Thiran or Gaussian), thus more settling time.